# Changing a file tree in tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository-design

We have a subversion repository which was set up without using the standard \trunk \tags \branch layout and now after a couple of years we are looking to rectify this. We use tortoiseSVN.

Our current system is that we have a "dev" folder with various subdirectories for UI, Business Logic, etc.

Ideally, we would want to have a dev folder, with trunk, branches and tags, then within the trunk folder our subdirectories.

My plan was to create the new trunk, branches, and tags folders under the dev folder and on the same level as our subdirectories, add and commit the new folders,  and then svnmove the subdirectories into the trunk folder.

I can do this on a up to date working copy; however, all of us have numerous local changes, and I fear that when we update we would inevitably get hundreds of tree conflicts. Can anyone see a better way of doing this?

The only option I can see is to individually copy all of the locally changed files from our current working copies into a fresh checkout of the repository and then delete the old working copy, but this isn't ideal. We have a lot of local changes and there's not likely to be a time when we *all* have a fairly up to date working copy.

Many thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

svn switch
http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is what I need, but I may not understand properly. I understand that I could switch my working copy from \dev to dev\trunk without hassle, but then surely when I update I wouldn't get anything above the trunk directory?

Have I not understood?

Answer (score 0):

You can commit all your local changes and then use Repo Browser to create the folder structure you want on the svn server (you can use drag & drop etc.). Once you're happy, you can then re-check out all your source.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't really feasible as we are all working on different projects which aren't finished so comitting all of our changes wouldn't work.